# Using DataContractJsonSerializer To Parse JSON To Dynamic Type In VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net, object, serialization, dynamic

I am using VB.NET to parse my SearchSpring JSON like this:

```
        Using ms As New MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json))
            Dim serializer As DataContractJsonSerializer = New DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType())
            obj = CType(serializer.ReadObject(ms), T)
            Return obj
        End Using
```

The problem is that JSON has different types for same attribute name ("value"):

```
{
  "field": "vanity_style_63",
  "value": "Transitional",
  "label": "Vanity Style: Transitional",
  "filterLabel": "Vanity Style",
  "filterValue": "Transitional"
},
{
"field": "vanity_width_88",
"value": {
      "rangeLow": "15",
      "rangeHigh": "24"
},
"label": "Vanity Width: 16\" to 24\"",
"filterLabel": "Vanity Width",
"filterValue": "16\" to 24\""
},
```

Sometimes it is string (in example - "Transitional"), sometimes it is an object.

I am using this class in serialization.

```
<DataContract()> _
Public Class FilterSummary
    <DataMember(Name:="field")> _
    Public Property Field As String
    <DataMember(Name:="filterLabel")> _
    Public Property FilterLabel As String
    <DataMember(Name:="filterValue")> _
    Public Property FilterValue As String
    <DataMember(Name:="label")> _
    Public Property Label As String
    <DataMember(Name:="value")> _
    Public Property Value As Object
End Class
```

It works when I have string there. However, when JSON has object there, I cannot access its values.

What should I do?

UPDATE:
This is how full valid JSON looks like:

```
{
    "filterSummary": [{
        "field": "vanity_width_88",
        "value": {
            "rangeLow": "15",
            "rangeHigh": "24"
        },
        "label": "Vanity Width: 16\" to 24\"",
        "filterLabel": "Vanity Width",
        "filterValue": "16\" to 24\""
    }, {
        "field": "vanity_width_88",
        "value": {
            "rangeLow": "35",
            "rangeHigh": "42"
        },
        "label": "Vanity Width: 35 to 42",
        "filterLabel": "Vanity Width",
        "filterValue": "35 to 42"
    }]
}
```

Comment: can you post enough of the json that it is valid.  Those appear to be part of a list or array.  Also, is there a reason the DataContractJsonSerializer must be used?